# Change sheet name in a link to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a very simple question but I am having trouble solving it.

Every month I need to update the data in a workbook based on what I have in another one.

In the source workbook the data is separated in different sheets for each month (Sheet name ex: Forecast Jan, Forecast Feb ...).

In the destination workbook, my links are pretty simple:

`=+'Q:\ ... \ [CLH_2016_01 Displaced inventory  2015-12-14.xlsm]**Forecast Aug**'!$C$65`

What I am looking for is a way to change `Forecast Aug` with `Forecast Sep`.

I have tried the easy way with Ctrl + H but I have over 4000 formulas to change and it takes a while (almost an hour if it does not crash before the end).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change calculations to manual and then try Ctrl + H

Comment: Your Find & Replace will likely be much quicker if you open the external file into the same application instance. The extended time to update would seem to be from re-evaluating each change individually.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! Both solutions work perfectly well (takes about 1s now) ! Have a nice day.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - how about making that an answer? You are welcome to include my suggestion as a secondary aspect toward an efficient method if you like.

Comment: @Jeeped : that's ok. you can make that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use indirect :

```
=INDIRECT("'Q:\ ... \ [CLH_2016_01 Displaced inventory 2015-12-14.xlsm]Forecast "&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm")&"'!$C$65")
```

However, this will work only if the external workbook is open, which might be a problem if you have several different workbooks.

In that case, the workaround I had done in my previous job was to use INDIRECT.EXT,  a function that performs INDIRECT and is able to check in closed workbooks.

However, this function is included in Morefunc.xll which is an external library, so you will require an installation.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solutions given by @Siddharth Rout and @Jeeped, here are two ways of improving the process:

-Change calculations to manual and then try Ctrl + H

-Your Find & Replace will likely be much quicker if you open the external file into the same application instance. The extended time to update would seem to be from re-evaluating each change individually.